# Group array of objects based on a key and return the new array of objects

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am having the below array of object on which I want to perform group based on entity name and I have see if two objects have same entity Name if yes then I have to see the color if color of both objects are same then I have to group them into one and combine the details of both.

If entity Name of two objects are same and color is different then I have to group them and set color as yellow and have to combine the details and return back the new array of objects.

```
let data = [
    {entityName: "Amazon", color: "red", details: "Hello"}
    {entityName: "Amazon", color: "green", details: "World"}
    {entityName: "Flipkart", color: "green", details: "1234567"} 
]
```

My excepted output from the above array should be this.

```
result = [
    {entityName: "Amazon", color: "yellow", details: "Hello world"}
    {entityName: "Flipkart", color: "green", details: "1234567"} 
]
```

Could anyone please tell me how can I do it?

Comment: Hmmm, pleasing merge results, but you'll need to specify merge logic for each property. Also can there be more than two of any given `entityName`?

Comment: There is not only one way to do it. What I would have tried to do is `filter` based on the number of item with the same `entityName` and `color`. Then `sort` your array by `entityName`. Finally, with a classic `for` loop, check if next element has the same `entityName`, if add `details` to current element and remove next.

Comment: @Marco could you please help me with an example

Comment: do you actually need to set it to `yellow`? or to the additive result of the two colors?

Comment: @pilchard yes I want to set it yellow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just iterate over items and find a matching item and implement your logic.

```js
let data = [{
    entityName: "Amazon",
    color: "red",
    details: "Hello"
  },
  {
    entityName: "Amazon",
    color: "green",
    details: "World"
  },
  {
    entityName: "Flipkart",
    color: "green",
    details: "1234567"
  }
];

var result = [];
for (const value of data) {
  const item = result.find(f => f.entityName === value.entityName);
  if (!item) {
    result.push(value);
  } else {
    if (item.color !== value.color) {
      item.color = 'yellow';
    }
    item.details += ' ' + value.details;
  }
}
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score -1):

You can loop through data and search for the index of the item that has the same name but different color (the if statement checks if indexOfFound >= 0 because if an item is not found, `findIndex` returns -1) mutate the item and then remove the item that was found.

So something like this:

```js
let data = [{
  entityName: "Amazon",
  color: "red",
  details: "Hello"
}, {
  entityName: "Amazon",
  color: "green",
  details: "World"
}, {
  entityName: "Flipkart",
  color: "green",
  details: "1234567"
}];

data.forEach(item => {
  const indexOfFound = data.findIndex(diffItem => diffItem.entityName == item.entityName && diffItem.color !== item.color);
  if (indexOfFound >= 0) {
    item.color = "yellow";
    item.details = `${item.details} ${data[indexOfFound].details.toLowerCase()}`
    data.splice(indexOfFound, 1);
  }
});

console.log(data);
```

Comment: You don't meet all the criteria.

Comment: Yeah, I realized that right after I posted, just edited it to meet the criteria.